Remove \r from a power automate string
I'm a noob to power automate and trying to read a csv file that I can process into a table that will be used in an email.
I was able to finally remove \n in power automate. How can I remove escape character \r from here?
I've tried things like:
string(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body'])
replace(replace(replace(outputs('Compose'), '\r\n', ''), '\n', ''), '\r', '')
split(outputs('Convert_to_String'), '\n')




Use Replace() function and denote \r as decodeUriComponent('%0A')
Sample:
replace('string\r',decodeUriComponent('%0A'),'')
Here are the keys:

decodeUriComponent('%0A') => \r
decodeUriComponent('%0D') => \n

Hope this helps.

Hi, I tried, but it did not work, the /r is still in the output. I added two images to my question to show your string and output.

Please ensure you're passing the string. You dont have any instance of 'string\r' in your input. The string needs to be passed only as first paramerer of replace. my string was 'string\r' it doesn't mean you will pass that too. you need to pass your own string.
